# Errata on Dummit and Foote, Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

This is from page 55 of Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra, 3rd edition. I am pretty sure the third line of the proof "$x^{b-a}=x^0=1$" is a typo and it should be "$x^{b-a}=1$, where $0<b-a<n$, contradicting the fact $|x|=n$".

I am not sure why $x^0$ is there. Could someone please clarify this? I looked up the list of errata but couldn't find anything about this.

Comment: I can't comment on the intention of making the remark, but it always holds (by definition) that $x^0 = 1$ and since $x^{b-a} = 1$, the equality *is* true (even though it may not be clarifying anything).

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 3):

Consider how one would get to $x^{b-a}$ from $x^b$. The most straightforward way is to multiply by $x^{-a}$. Thus, given the equation $$x^b=x^a$$ we get $x^{b-a}=x^{a-a}=x^0$ after multiplying by $x^{-a}$ on both sides. This is likely to be the origin of the mysterious $x^0$ term.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you so much.